# Recursive tree-building function only maps over one child

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm attempting to recursively build a tree.   The following class builds the tree into a Hash by recursively calling the `.children` getter.

```
class Tree
  attr_reader :root

  def initialize(uri:)
    @root     = Article.new(uri: uri)
    @children = nil
  end

  def children(depth: 3, article_children: self.root.child_links)
    @children ||= article_children.map do |uri|
      puts "URI: #{uri}"
      if (depth == 0)
        return Article.new(uri: uri)
      else
        article = Article.new(uri: uri)
        return { article => self.children(depth: depth - 1, article_children: article.child_links) }
      end
    end

    puts JSON.pretty_generate(@children)
    return @children
  end
end
```

I expect the resulting JSON to look something like this:

```
{
      "#<Article:0x00007ff1a33c06d0>": {
        "#<Article:0x00007ff1a345e920>": {
          "#<Article:0x00007ff1a3989418>": ["#<Article:0x00007ff1a423f698>", ...]
        },
        "#<Article:0x00007ff1a345e920>": {
          "#<Article:0x00007ff1a3989418>": ["#<Article:0x00007ff1a423f698>", ...]
        },
        "#<Article:0x00007ff1a345e920>": {
          "#<Article:0x00007ff1a3989418>": ["#<Article:0x00007ff1a423f698>", ...]
        },
        "#<Article:0x00007ff1a345e920>": {
          "#<Article:0x00007ff1a3989418>": ["#<Article:0x00007ff1a423f698>", ...]
        },
        "#<Article:0x00007ff1a345e920>": {
          "#<Article:0x00007ff1a3989418>": ["#<Article:0x00007ff1a423f698>", ...]
        },
      }
    }
}
```

However, the prettified JSON ends up looking like this:

```
{
  "#<Article:0x00007ff1a33c06d0>": {
    "#<Article:0x00007ff1a345e920>": {
      "#<Article:0x00007ff1a3989418>": "#<Article:0x00007ff1a423f698>"
    }
  }
}
```

And `puts "URI: #{uri}` within `article.children.map` outputs

```
URI: https://child.uri.org/example/uri
URI: https://child.uri.org/example/uri1
URI: https://child.uri.org/example/uri2
URI: https://child.uri.org/example/uri3
```

Each of these URIs is the first child URI of each article object.

*Why is map only processing the first element, and not the entirety of the array?*

Comment: If you're going to leave a close vote, kindly leave a reason so I can improve this and future questions.

Comment: Why do you have `return`s inside your `map` block? Also, won't you have problems with `self.children(depth: ...)` using the same `@children` instance variable has the outer `children` call?

Comment: @muistooshort unless I'm mistaken explicitly stating a return inside of a `map` block is returned the resulting array.  I'm explicitly returning here because I have a map that encompasses several lines.

Comment: @muistooshort You're probably right on the `@children` part.  I've actually ripped that part out since posting the question.

Comment: How are you calling `children` method? What arguments are you using?

Comment: `return` will end the parent function, not the block. You can replace `return` in the block with `next` if you want the iteration to continue to the next item.

Comment: I think that's my problem.  I was mistaken. @maxpleaner

Comment: @muistooshort ^

Comment: This was definitely my problem.  I'd be willing to mark this as the answer.

Comment: @maxpleaner Do you want to convert that comment to an answer so that they have something to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` keyword in a block will not just end the block, it will end the parent function (in this case, the `def children`).

So, you are not returning the result of `map` as you intend, but are having the entire fuction return after the first iteration. It will still fire the recursive calls, but in each recursive invocation the same behavior will happen. That's why you're seeing nesting in your result, but each level only has one element and not an array.

So, you can simply remove the `return` words and keep everything else the same. Keep in mind that `return` is never necessary anyway unless you are forcing an early return from a method.

Alternatively, you can replace `return` with `next`, which is a special keyword used in enumerable functions to go the next iteration. Like `return`, it can be passed an argument which becomes the returned value of the block for that iteration. For more info, see http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_Expressions_Break_Redo_and_Next.html or other resources.